# SPContext on Forms login page

Tags: forms-authentication, login, security-token-service

How can I get the `SPContext` on the forms login page (/_forms/default.aspx)?  Looking up `SPContext.Current` or `SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current)` is always null.  I need to retrieve the parent WebApplication and IIS Settings prior to logon in order to retrieve a Form Membership Provider within the `SecurityTokenService` Application's web.config.

I'm open to alternatives to identifying the current Web Application and Zone in order to retrieve the Forms Membership Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MembershipProvider and RoleProvider classes provide the name (this.Name) of the membership/role provider.